# Почему в русском языке появляются заимствованные слова?

Tags: заимствования

Интересует, почему в русском языке настолько много заимствованных слов!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, так получилось. Заимствованные слова обычно (я так думаю) появляются вместе с явлениями и предметами, которые они обозначают. При этом есть два пути — или заимствовать слово от соседей, которые уже умеют называть эти предметы или явления, или изобретать новое слово из русских морфем. Ну, например, практически все за рубежом говорят "helicopter", у нас — "вертолет". При этом, картофель — производное от заимствования из немецкого "Kartoffel". Также есть заимствование из русского языка в других, так что этот процесс всеобщий.

Answer (score 3):

Почему происходит заимствование или почему так много заимствованных слов? Их ещё больше, чем Вы подозреваете, только они уже прижились и воспринимаются как наши родные. О  пользе этого явления говорить не стоит - это развитие языка, а вот почему так много"дублёров" русских слов  - это от уровня культуры носителей языка. Всё должно быть в меру и обусловлено необходимостью. А у нас как всегда - "всего и побольше". Потому и встаёт вопрос о бережном отношении к родному языку.

Comment: Они не просто воспринимаются "как наши родные", а родными являются. То, что слово пришло 300-400 лет назад из другого языка, не отменяет того, что сейчас это слово русское, тем более если оно обрусело по произношению и органично вписалось в русскую грамматику. Считаю, что называть заимствованными слова, которые многие сотни лет являются частью нашего языка — это либо глупость, либо научное шарлатанство, либо намеренная провокация.

Answer (score 1):

Заимствованных слов в русском не больше, чем во многих других европейских языках. Если копнуть глубже, то окажется, что многие английские, немецкие, французские слова пришли из латинского и греческого языков. Другое дело, что я не вижу смысла называть заимствованными слова, которые не одну сотню лет являются частью языка.

Comment: @Пересвет О Вы владеете всеми европейскими языками? Поздравляю! Сейчас уже больше, чем во всех других, кроме албанского и румынского. А в восточных языках заимствований вообще нет. Английский и французский - это языки которые ФОРМИРОВАЛИСЬ на базе латинского, почти так же, как русский на основе славянского. Этот пример не уместный. И вообще, это происходило в средние века, когда латинский и греческий были языками культуры. Сейчас же заимствует только русский, не считая папуасский и пигмейских языков.

Comment: Думаю, врать всё-таки нужно аккуратнее, можно ведь и поймать за руку. Японский, стало быть, к восточным языкам не относится? И кто вам вообще сказал, что английский сформировался на базе латинского? Тогда уж и русский оттуда же. Хороший язык, латинский, раз уж всё из него, связанное и никак не связанное.

Comment: Английский и французский принадлежат к разным ветвям индроевропейской языковой семьи, французский с латинским связан генетически, а английский - нет. В то же время русский генетически связан с праславянским языком.

Comment: В японском языке после Второй Мировой войны была проведена чистка от американизмов. Уж японцы-то умеют себя уважать. Даже чуточку презирать европейцев, если уж совсем начистоту.

Answer (score 1):

В русском языке достаточно мало более-менее новых заимствований, которые вы можете опознать (прилично есть старых, вроде "собака", "лошадь", "сладкий", "время", "хлеб", "шнурок", "власть").

Можете сами проверить, взяв вместо словаря частотный словарь:
http://dict.ruslang.ru/freq.php?act=show&dic=freq_freq&title=%D7%E0%F1%F2%EE%F2%ED%FB%E9%20%F1%EF%E8%F1%EE%EA%20%EB%E5%EC%EC

И обнаружится, что у нас, безусловно есть масса слов вроде "менеджер", "анализировать", "дизайн", но в основном мы говорим не их  (а вот в английском французская лексика укоренилась глубже). Костяк языка составляют славянские слова и заимствования из церковнославянского. Можно даже сказать, что современный литературный русский язык это и есть результат их смешения: как известно, церковнославянский долго был "высоким" языком, но деловые документы всё же пытались писать языком, более приближенным к живой речи.

По-видимому, в последнее время так много заимствований, потому что в мире появляется очень много нового (компьютеры, конечно же), а русский оказался достаточно шустрым языком, который легко тащит новые слова и заставляет работать по своим законам. У нас ведь и звуковая система достаточно развита (не приходится думать, как бы передать слово), и падежи уже готовы. Даже для глаголов есть устоявшиеся практики (очень часто из заимствованного слова легко образовать глагол на ***-ить***, ***-овать*** или ***-ировать***).